# Split string into chunks at the closest space not exceeding specified chunk length

Tags: vba

I built the following code to split a string (which will have a variable number of characters, let's say from 50 to 1000) to an array.

I need the chunks to be no more than 100 characters and split at the closest space before 100 (no cuts in the middle of the words).

The loop functions the first time, cutting at the closest space before 100.
If more than one split is needed, it starts chunking in the middle of the words.

```vb
Function SplitString(ByVal str As String, ByVal numOfChar As Long) As String()
    
    Dim sArr() As String
    Dim nCount As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    
    ReDim sArr((Len(str)) \ numOfChar)
       
    While Not Mid(str, x, 1) = " "
        x = x - 1
    Wend
    
    Do While Len(str)
        sArr(nCount) = Left$(str, x)
        str = Mid$(str, x + 1)
        nCount = nCount + 1
    Loop
    SplitString = sArr
End Function
```

Comment: Have you already determined that it would not be easier to `Split` using a space as the delimiter first? Then re-assemble based on the string length? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: I am here to ask for help. I have commercial items descriptions to split, so there's a space between each word, I supposed that using the space as first delimiter would generate a lot of useless loops...

Comment: Brax is giving good advice. You need to read up on split, collections and join.

Comment: Plese, try better describing what you mean by "cutting at the closest space before 100, then if more than one split is needed, it starts chunking between words". What is to be done with the rest of the string? Keep splitting on the same logic (closest space before 100), or splitting by every space of the remaining string? I would mostly like understanding what you mean by **it starts chunking between word**...

Comment: Hi Eleonora.  As a new contributor you should be aware that you are supposed to mark one of the answers as accepted.  It is considered rude if you post a question and never respond to the answers.

Comment: Thank you, I was not able to connect until this morning (not my intention to be rude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a collection. I think it's the neatest and most readable way.

```vb
Function SplitByChunk(str As String, chunkLen As Long, Optional char As String = " ") As String()
    Dim splits() As String
    splits = Split(str, char)
    
    Dim i As Long, cLen As Long, chunk As String
    Dim chunks As New Collection
    For i = 0 To UBound(splits)
'       Add chunk to chunks if the next word pushes it over length.
        If Len(chunk & splits(i)) > chunkLen Then
            chunks.Add Trim(chunk)
            chunk = ""
        End If
        
        chunk = chunk & " " & splits(i)
    Next i
    chunks.Add Trim(chunk)
    
    Dim results() As String
    If chunks.Count = 0 Then
        ReDim results(0)
        SplitByChunk = results
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ReDim results(0 To chunks.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To chunks.Count
        results(i - 1) = chunks(i)
    Next i
    SplitByChunk = results
End Function
```

You can test by passing in a string and observing the results.

```vb
Sub test_SplitByChunk()
    Dim s() As String
    s = SplitByChunk("A goose once bit my sister right on the nose!", 10)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(s)
        Debug.Print Len(s(i)), s(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Printed to Immediate:

```
 7            A goose
 8            once bit
 9            my sister
 8            right on
 9            the nose!
```

Comment: I made a couple of tests and the code posted by SSlinky works exactly as expected.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be achieved with a single loop.

To make life easier I've used the ArrayList as the vehicle for storing substrings.

The code below splits the input string into individual substrings, and then reassembles arraylists of substrings that fit the criteria of being less than a certain size.

You end up with an ArrayList of ArrayLists

```
Option Explicit

' This code uses the ArrayList object and thus requires a reference to msCorlib.dll
' e.g. Tools.References, scrolldown and check the tickbox for mscorlib.dll

' We use the ArrayList because it has a 'ToArray' Method and we don't have to worry
' about resizing arrays

' We return an ArrayList because this allows for more flexibility in subsequent processing
' To get a string back from myAL use    VBA.Join(myAL(x).ToArray, " ")

Public Function SplitString(ByRef ipString As String, Optional ByVal ipSize As Long = 100) As ArrayList

    Dim myAL As ArrayList
    Set myAL = New ArrayList
    Set SplitString = myAL
    
    If VBA.Len(ipString) = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim myStrings As Variant
    myStrings = VBA.Split(ipString, " ")
    
    Dim mySize As Long
    Dim myString As Variant
    Dim myInnerList As ArrayList
    Set myInnerList = New ArrayList
    For Each myString In myStrings
    
        ' The +1 accounts for the fact that we will reassemble strings with spaces between
        ' and ensures that the reassembled string will not exceed ipSize
        If mySize + VBA.Len(myString) + 1 > ipSize + 1 Then
        
            myAL.Add myInnerList
            Set myInnerList = New ArrayList
            mySize = 0
            
        End If
        
        myInnerList.Add myString
        mySize = mySize + VBA.Len(myString)
            
    Next

End Function
```

I've not tested this code, but have checked with Rubberduck and there are no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It returns an array of strings, no longer then `numOfChar`, but ending where a space exists:

```
Function SplitString_(ByVal str As String, ByVal numOfChar As Long) As String()
    Dim strArr() As String, strElem As String, firstChar As Long, elimChars As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    Const maxLimit As Long = 100
    
    If numOfChar > maxLimit Then Exit Function 'not allowing splitting for more than 100 characters
    firstChar = 1
    ReDim strArr(Int(Len(str) / numOfChar) + 2) 'redim it at a maximum number of elements, to accept maximum of needed strings
    If Len(str) > numOfChar Then                              'split only if is the case:
        For i = 1 To UBound(strArr)
            strElem = Mid(str, firstChar, numOfChar)
            If firstChar + Len(strElem) - 1 = Len(str) Then   'condition to exit function when the last necessary element has been found
                strArr(k) = strElem: ReDim Preserve strArr(k) 'preserving the array content before returning (to eliminate the empty elements)
                SplitString_ = strArr: Exit Function
            End If
            If Mid(str, Len(strElem) + Len(Join(strArr, "")) + firstChar, 1) = " " Then 'process the case when AFTER the obtained string IS a space:
                strArr(k) = strElem: k = k + 1: firstChar = firstChar + Len(strElem) + 1: strElem = ""
            ElseIf Right(strElem, 1) = " " Then                            'process the case when the obtaind string ends in a space
                strArr(k) = left(strElem, Len(strElem) - 1)
                k = k + 1: firstChar = firstChar + Len(strElem): strElem = ""
            Else                                                            'the rest of possibilities
                'go back to the first space:
                elimChars = Len(strElem) - InStrRev(strElem, " ") + 1
                strArr(k) = left(strElem, Len(strElem) - elimChars)
                k = k + 1: firstChar = firstChar + Len(strElem) - elimChars + 1: strElem = ""
            End If
        Next i
    Else
      ReDim strArr(0): strArr(0) = str 'return an array of a single element
    End If
End Function
```

You can  test it with the next `Sub` and its stupid string:

```
Sub testSplitString_()
   Dim x As String, arr() As String
   x = "my string to be tested and something more should to be achieved and blah, blah, blah to the sky and more"
   arr = SplitString_(x, 20)
End Sub
Please, play with the second parameter and see the result in `Immediate Window` (`Ctrl + G` being in Visual Basic for Applications Editor).
```